# Mysql: How do I subtract a percentage from a number

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Columns

```
amount:  500
discount_percentage: 50
```

How do I select to end up with an amount of 250?

Thanks

J

Comment: `SELECT (amount * ((100 - discount_percentage) / 100)) FROM tableA`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT amount - (amount * discount_percentage / 100)
FROM tableA;
```

Answer (score 4):

try using this:

```
SELECT (amount * ((100 - discount_percentage) / 100)) as result FROM tableA
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple method.

```
SELECT amount * .50
FROM TableA;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS REMOVE_PERCENT;
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION REMOVE_PERCENT(amount decimal(10,2),perc INT(10))
RETURNS decimal(10,2)
RETURN amount - (amount*perc/100);
```

And now you can use it

```
SELECT REMOVE_PERCENT(amount,discount_percentage) FROM tableA;
SELECT REMOVE_PERCENT(amount,discount_percentage) FROM tableB;
UPDATE tableA SET `result` = REMOVE_PERCENT(amount,discount_percentage) WHERE `discount_percentage` >0
```